# How to publish both Sphinx generated docs and Markdown on GitHub Pages at the same time?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, python-sphinx

I'd like to publish both Sphinx generated docs for a Python project *and* Markdown content in the same GitHub Pages project.

Because Sphinx docs contain folders starting with an underscore, e.g., `_static`, and Jekyll treats those as special, the general recommendation seems to be so simply place a `.nojekyll` file into the GitHub Pages root directory.

Unfortunately, I also want to publish some content that is written in Markdown and that needs Jekyll to be rendered correctly.

The idea is to have the Sphinx docs in a subfolder called `docs` and the Markdown content in the root folder. Roughly like this:

```
root-+-docs-+-_static--+--...
     |      +-_sources-+--...
     +-somefile.md
```

Using `.nojekyll` is not an option, because then `somefile.md` would not be rendered.

It seems to me that I should be able to solve this with the [`include` directive](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/options/).

> Force inclusion of directories and/or files in the conversion.  `.htaccess` is a good example since dotfiles are excluded by default.

So I tried the following `_config.yml` (placed in the root folder):

```
github: [metadata]
encoding: UTF-8
kramdown:
    input: GFM
    hard_wrap: false
    toc_levels: 1..3
future: true
jailed: false
theme: jekyll-theme-cayman
gfm_quirks: paragraph_end
include: ['docs/_static/','docs/_sources/','docs/_modules/']
```

Unfortunately, this config still leads to 404s when trying to load anything from `docs/_static/`.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution seems to be to simply use two GitHub repositories:

- One for Sphinx (with `.nojekyll`)
- One for the Markdown content